# Hey, can anyone help me initialize commentbox.io code in my weebly website?

Tags: javascript, plugins, initialization, comments, weebly

I want to place a comment box on my website.

This is the code for installation of the plugin:

```
<script  src="https://unpkg.com/commentbox.io/dist/commentBox.min.js"></script>
```

which I have already placed inside the head section on my website. No problem here.

Then we have to initialize this code:

```
import commentBox from 'commentbox.io';

commentBox('my-project-id');
```

I am not able to figure this out how and where to add the above initialization code on my website? I tried adding in the head but nothing happened (I already know that I have to place the project id, even with project id it's not showing)!

Comment: Import is used in JavaScript modules, not just in a js tag on a webpage

Comment: Hey, I am not a developer, can you provide the complete code, I searched the net, after that I came to know that it will look like this: <script type="module">
import commentBox from 'commentbox.io';
commentBox('my-project-id');
</script>               Is is correct? But where to place it, in the head section or in the body?

Comment: See the answer. It is complete

Answer (score 0):

Like this

You will need some kind of setup too since here at SO there are some restrictions

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Comments</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/commentbox.io/dist/commentBox.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener("load",function() {
      commentBox('my-project-id');
    });
   </script>
</head>  
<body>
<div class="commentbox"></div>
</body>
</html>
```